# Can you reverse 'ubuntu-drivers autoinstall'?

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-drivers

I'm relatively new to Linux. I recently had a functioning Ubuntu 20.04 which wasn't recognizing that I had plugged in a display via HDMI to my ASUS ZenBook laptop. I read a couple of articles and found the `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` command which suggested that  updating the Nvidia graphics driver might fix the issue.

After updating all my drivers as well as Nvidia, my laptop couldn't boot. It would simply cycle between the boot window and a message saying "SGX disabled by BIOS". Using `purge` I removed all Nvidia drivers from my machine and managed to boot to desktop, however there are now several drivers that are seeming to fail, presumably from the `autoinstall`. These include important things such as the touchpad and wireless connection functionality.

I also attempted the steps detailed in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely) which suggests installing `ubuntu-desktop` post purge.

Is there a command or process I can use to basically purge all faulty/incompatible drivers I may have installed with `autoinstall`, perhaps back to the base Ubuntu 20.04 image as my machine was functional out the box with a fresh installation?

EDIT:

`uname -a`
Linux james-ZenBook-UX535LI-UX535LI 5.15.0-33-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 13:34:26 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

`lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280`
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:06f0]
DeviceName: WLAN
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz [8086:0074]

Comment: You need to disable Secure Boot in UEFI when using proprietary drivers (or use MOKutil to sign the drivers). You can do that in any situation except if dual-booting with Window 11 for which Secure Boot is a requirement.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The current issue is occuring with Secure Boot Control switched off in BIOS. Though I didn't know that so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To remove all the proprietary nvidia packages run the following commands.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia'
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo reboot
```

Since you made some other big changes to your installed software besides uninstalling the Nvidia proprietary graphics drivers, I wouldn't automatically assume that the autoinstall option of ubuntu-drivers caused so many things to fail. In fact you might need to reverse some other commands.

You may be facing a situation which requires you to either reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 or fresh install Ubuntu 22.04. If your laptop is a recent model, a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 will get you out of reverse gear and give you a more up-to-date kernel and proprietary graphics drivers.

Comment: I believe I have tried this command in addition to `purge`. I think I needed to add a wildcard for the remove arg. `sudo apt remove '^nvidia-*'`

Comment: @karel I may be wrong, but `apt` doesn't use regexps opposed to `apt-get`. This may confuse people. Your command is good for `apt-get`.