# After updating nvidia drivers, almost everything stopped working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

Here is what happened.

- I wanted to install Lutris to play games on my laptop (ASUS X756UX, Ubuntu 20.04), and the website advises to check that the graphics drivers are installed and up to date. Being a complete novice when it comes to drivers on a Linux distro, I followed [this guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/).
- I went to Software & Updates > Other drivers and selected 'NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-510' (I was using the 470 version previously).
- I went ahead with the thing; the old driver was uninstalled and the new one installed, then I was asked to create a Secure Boot MOK password, which I did.
- I rebooted as prompted.

After I logged in, I discovered I have no more sound, no network access, and the touchpad doesn't work.
I can log in, use the keyboard and an external USB mouse.
If I plug in a USB drive, it doesn't automatically mount and it's not even detected by `fdisk -l`.
I also noticed that the system takes a much longer time to shutdown now.
Also at boot, just before the log in screen, I get the message `/dev/sda2: clean, <big number>/<big number> files, <big number>/<big number> blocks`, similarly to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68124511/booting-error-dev-sda2-clean-files-blocks), except I don't get stuck there.

If I boot from a Live USB Ubuntu 20.04 everything works normally.

As far as I can tell, a lot of modules aren't being loaded ; here is the output from `lsmod`:

```
   Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
kvm_intel             303104  0
kvm                   864256  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           376832  0
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
input_leds             16384  0
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
efi_pstore             16384  0
serio_raw              20480  0
acpi_pad              184320  0
video                  53248  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  1
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler       114688  1 ipmi_devintf
msr                    16384  0
parport_pc             45056  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
drm                   557056  0
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               49152  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
ahci                   40960  2
xhci_pci               24576  0
libahci                36864  1 ahci
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
```

How can I fix this? Did I do anything wrong? Also, how can I avoid this in the future?
If nothing works I will reinstall Ubuntu, but I would like to keep this as a last resort.

Thanks.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have already done that, the problem stays unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you reverse 'ubuntu-drivers autoinstall'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410298/can-you-reverse-ubuntu-drivers-autoinstall)